# Elegant way to handle null -- Only single null value required amongst 2 variables

Tags: java, logic

Is there a better way to solve this problem?
I have two variables X & Y. X & Y both can’t be null. Both of them can’t be set. Only 1 of them should be null

For ex:

```
if (x && y)
    return err;
if (x == null && y == null)
    return err;
if (x)
 …do something with x
if (y)
..do something with y
```

Comment: Sounds like a code smell. You most likely have deeper design issues. Would definutely help if your code example wasn't as broad (used concrete information, such as what those variables are for)

Answer (score 6):

You can merge the error checks like this:

```
if ((x == null) == (y == null)) {
    return err;
}
if (x != null) {
    // do something with x
} else {
    // do something with y
}
```

Comment: For the other way, i.e. `((x == null) != (y == null))`, you can also use the [boolean logical exclusive-or operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2), i.e. `((x == null) ^ (y == null))`, which, because of operator precedence rules, don't need extra parenthesis, i.e. `(x == null ^ y == null)`.

Answer (score 0):

This question is more appropriate for [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com), but it's generally better to avoid clever code.  If you particularly want to merge the two error cases, just write

```
if (x != null && y == null) {
    // do something with x
} else if (y != null && x == null) {
    // do something with y
} else {
    return err;
}
```